How can i deform a group of objects with a modifier or empty?
If i have a simple model, with separate objects (which i dont really want to make them join together) but i need to deform it, like a cartoon, how can i achieve this? i made a very simpler model as an example:

This object is like a vehicle, and i added a Empty to show how can i add an object like this (with hopefully more vertices) in order to deform it.
For example, to do something like on this image, where you can expand the model cartoony with an external modifier:

Is there any way to do this?

Hello, you can deform your objects with a Lattice modifier, have you already tried?

Thank you!!! it worked! It's exactly what I needed, put it as an answer and I'll give you validation.

Use the Lattice modifier: Create a lattice object, scale it in Object mode so that it contains your object, subdivide it as much as needed (Data panel > Resolution), give your object a Lattice modifier, switch your lattice to Edit mode and modify it, the object will be deformed accordingly:


Thank you very much!
